# Implementing autosave function in Python after performing my task

Tags: python, linux

In Linux konsole, I try to add some new entries replacing the old entries in my project in my tool.

Passing the command like ToolName -f  --project  --replaceEntities  but I need to save and exit every time once the replacement is done. I want to autosave the function and also autoexit once the replacement is done. So what kind of function do  have to implement to auotsave and exit the tool.

Note: The replacement entities has been developed in Python.

Comment: What's the difference between `exit` and `autoexit`?

Comment: @PeterWood I need to pass the command, once the operation has been performed I need to save and exit manually but I dont want to do it manually. Once I pass the replacement command It has to automatically save and exit the tool after the task has been done.

Answer (score 0):

is this you want?

```
#! /bin/sh
# your_task.sh

python your_task.py > /var/log/your_task.log 2> /var/log/your_task.err.log
```

then you can use like this

```
./your_task.sh
```